# Problems with QueueingNetworkProcess

Tags: manipulate, core-language, queueing-systems

I have a two stage queueing network and want to vary the number of servers at the second node. The input data and the `Manipulate` command is below:

```
γ = {40, 0}; μ = {4/3, 60/4};
r = {{0, 1}, {0, 0}};
c = {∞, s};
shoppingProcess[s_] := QueueingNetworkProcess[γ, r, μ, c];

Manipulate[
 QueueProperties[{shoppingProcess[s_], 1}, "MeanSystemSize"] + 
   QueueProperties[{shoppingProcess[s_], 2}, "MeanSystemSize"] // 
  N, {s, 3, 5, 1}]
```

When I execute it, it computes the first queue quantity but does not compute the second queue value. It seems that the variable `s` is not passed to `c`.

Comment: Evaluate `QueueProperties[{shoppingProcess[3], 2}, "MeanSystemSize"]` . It doesn't seem related to `Manipulate[ ]`

Comment: Your code is not valid actually. You are calling the function using `shoppingProcess[s_]`. This should be the definition of the function, not in the call. In the call, do not use `_` on the argument.

Answer (score 3):

#### Edit

I have edited this answer to address issues raised by the OP in a deleted answer that should have been posted as a comment to this one.

There seem to be two problems with your code.

1. This is one of those times when you must use `Set` rather than `SetDelayed` when defining a function.
2. You shouldn't use `s_` in a function call, as you did in your `Manipulate` expression

I made the indicated corrections to your code.

```
γ = {40, 0}; 
μ = {4/3, 60/4};
r = {{0, 1.}, {0, 0}};
c = {∞, s};

shoppingProcess[s_] = QueueingNetworkProcess[γ, r, μ, c];
Manipulate[
  With[{sp = shoppingProcess[s]},
    QueueProperties[{sp, 1}, "MeanSystemSize"] + 
      QueueProperties[{sp, 2}, "MeanSystemSize"]],
  {s, 3, 5, 1}]
```

With these changes

[image: demo]

`Set` should be used in place of `SetDelayed` so that the `s` that appears on the definition of `c` gets evaluated in the local scope of your `Manipulate` expression.  Another, and I think better, way to write your `Manipulate` expression is

```
With[{
    γ = {40, 0},
    μ = {4/3, 60/4},
    r = {{0, 1.}, {0, 0}}},
  DynamicModule[{c, sp},
    Manipulate[
      c = {∞, s};
      sp = QueueingNetworkProcess[γ, r, μ, c];
      QueueProperties[{sp, 1}, "MeanSystemSize"] + 
        QueueProperties[{sp, 2}, "MeanSystemSize"],
      {s, 3, 5, 1}]]]
```

which makes the scoping very clear. Still another way, and the way I would write the code for myself, is

```
With[{
    γ = {40, 0},
    μ = {4/3, 60/4},
    r = {{0, 1.}, {0, 0}}},
  Manipulate[
    sp = QueueingNetworkProcess[γ, r, μ, {∞, s}];
    QueueProperties[{sp, 1}, "MeanSystemSize"] + 
      QueueProperties[{sp, 2}, "MeanSystemSize"],
    {sp, None},
    {s, 3, 5, 1}]]
```

This 2nd rewrite is more succinct but more obscure, especially for those who have little experience with `Manipulate`. Because it eliminates `c` altogether, it eliminates any scoping problems `c` might introduce. Making `sp` an invisible control may be obscurantist, but is a well-known trick for creating a variable in the local scope of a `Manipulate` expression.